# How do I perform a batch delete with the playframework / jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I recently started falling in love with the play! framework but now I am confused about how to use the batch delete method on a Model.
My attempt looks like this:

```
Shift.delete("byDateAndRestaurant", day, rest);
```

This, however, does not work. play! just throws this back at me:

> IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: byDateAndRestaurant near line 1, column 41 [delete from models.Shift where byDateAndRestaurant]

which is very confusing as this code works flawlessly:

```
Shift.find("byDateAndRestaurant", day, rest).fetch();
```

(Of course, I could just loop through the results of the `find` query and delete each instance. But I don't want to cause too many database interactions.)

So what kind of query/shortcut notation does the `delete` method accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Shift.delete("Date=? AND Restaurant=?", day, rest);
```

should work fine.

Comment: once I lowercased the attributes it worked just fine. Thanks a lot!